# User login only by password

Tags: joomla-3.x, login, account-password

My goal is to let user possibility to login using only password. There is any available plugin or module for that? I had a problem to find it.

thanks

Comment: In my nine years of dealing with Joomla, I've never heard of such a concept. Logging user without username or email, only with password? So, you except that password would be only login data which will differentiate users between themselves? If that is possible by some chance, I humbly accept that I don't know a rat's ass about Joomla

Comment: multiple users can have same passwords then how you will differentiate them?

Comment: I don't want to differentiate them. This is website of some conference and during the manually registration to this conference (somewhere in physical office), participants get the password to resources available only for registered participants. 
I know it is easy to walk around by users but client doesn't want to create a separate account for each participant and insist to one password for everyone.

Comment: As suggested already, I think your best option is to password protect the ur via your .htaccess

Answer (score 2):

**Content Password Plugin**

The [Content Password](http://progandy.de/contentpassword.html) plugin worked well to password protect content on a Joomla page but unfortunately was not updated by the developer for newer versions of Joomla.

Fortunately, it looks like someone has resurrected the project for Joomla 3.x at: https://github.com/projoomexperts/Joomla-Content-Password-3

**JLex Block** from $29

[JLex Block](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/access-a-security/site-access/jlex-block) can "Set a password for any number of page or elements on page."

**.htaccess/.htpasswd Password Protection**

You may be able to password protect a Joomla page using .htaccess and .htpasswd. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/14603568/1983389 for some options.